# Chrome not showing up in vscode. Manjaro Linux

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-web

i'm on Manjaro. i've install google-chrome from [`AUR`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/google-chrome/) and it shows up in flutter doctor , flutter devices when executed from terminal. the problem is when i run flutter doctor from vscode it says

> [✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find chrome executable at google-chrome)
>       ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First you need to switch master channel

```sh
flutter channel master
```

Then run

```sh
flutter upgrade
```

Enable Web support by running

```sh
flutter config --enable-web
```

Find installation path of chrome by running

```sh
which chrome
```

set an Environment variable to chrome's installation path.
If your installed using AUR it will in /opt/google/chrome/chrome

```sh
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

Finally run

```sh
flutter devices
```

You can see chrome as a connected device.

Answer (score 15):

To use chrome or chromium on Linux(Manjaro), first you have to find their location.

Run the following command:

```sh
which chromium
```

My chromium is located at:

```sh
/usr/bin/chromium
```

If you wish to add this browser to `Flutter`, then you should add it to the `CHROME_EXECUTABLE` environment variable.

the following command needs to be placed in the `.bashrc`:

> `/usr/bin/chromium` is my chromium location; add yours.

You can use `nano`:

```sh
nano .bashrc
```

Add the following command and press `Ctrl+x` and then `Y` to make sure it has been saved.

```sh
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/chromium
```

And finally run:

```sh
source .bashrc
```

Now restart the previous open IDE and it should work.
If you run:

```sh
flutter doctor
```

You should find it in the `connected device`.

Comment: While this answer is rather for linux users, for macOS PATH look like this on macOS: `export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`

Answer (score 4):

check $PATH

try to chrome- and tab

```sh
ln -s /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable /usr/local/bin/google-chrome
```

Answer (score 2):

run flutter pub global activate webdev

Answer (score 1):

If you are using brave browser on Manjaro, open the terminal and start here:

```
which brave-browser
```

My brave is located at:

```
/usr/bin/brave-browser
```

Then you can run the executable:

```
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/brave-browser
```

Then you can run flutter devices:

```
flutter devices
```

The output of flutter devices should be:

```
1 connected device:

Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Brave Browser 96.1.33.80 unknown
```

Run flutter doctor in verbose:

```
flutter doctor -v
```

Here's the output all green:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.6.0-12.0.pre.999, on Manjaro Linux
    5.9.16-1-MANJARO, locale en_US.utf8)
    • Flutter version 2.6.0-12.0.pre.999 at /home/mbuso/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 895beb04bb (33 hours ago), 2021-12-10 18:54:10 -0800
    • Engine revision 79f750d4a5
    • Dart version 2.16.0 (build 2.16.0-85.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.9.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/mbuso/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /opt/android-sdk
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • CHROME_EXECUTABLE = /usr/bin/brave

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 62.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 203.8452
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2)
    • IntelliJ at /usr/share/idea
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Brave Browser 96.1.33.80 unknown

• No issues found!
```

To make sure that the export executes on every start you can include this line in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc depending on which shell you use:

```
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/brave-browser
```

Comment: For me, I it didn't worked. I had to add the line export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/usr/bin/chromium" into home>~./bashrc file. Then it started showing

Comment: Yeah man...I forgot to include the export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/brave in the ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc. Thank you